# OpenCV поиск, учитывая цвет

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Как сделать, чтобы `matchTemplate` находил совпадения, учитывая цвет? Любое изменение кода даёт ошибку. Я понимаю, что в коде используется cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, меняю на cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB - возникает ошибка. Приведу пример: есть шарики одинаковой формы, но разных цветов и почти одинаковых размеров. Нужно найти шарик определенного цвета. Решить эту задачу я смог, вырезав найденный объект, чтобы определить его цвет, но хотелось бы иметь более чистый код..

Документация. https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def searchObjectInImage(img, tpl, acc):
    img = cv2.imread(img)
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    template = cv2.imread(tpl, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    w,h = template.shape[::-1]

    result = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_img,template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    loc = np.where(result >= acc)

    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(img, pt,(pt[0] + w,pt[1] +h), (0,255,0),3)
        
    cv2.imshow("img",img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY, меняю на cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB - возникает ошибка.

Могу только предположить, что это связано с разной размерностью gray_img и template. То есть вы пытаетесь по изображению с тремя каналами искать совпадение с шаблоном с одним каналом.

Иными словами, замените строчку `template = cv2.imread(tpl, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`
на `template = cv2.imread(tpl, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)` или вовсе не указывайте параметр flag (по умолчанию `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR`). Изображение template будет в трех каналах BGR. То есть вам нужно сделать либо еще одну конвертацию template в RGB, или убрать конвертацию gray_img в RGB.

Comment: В таком случае возникнет ошибка. : ( w,h = template.shape[::-1]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: `(h, w) = template.shape[:2]` будет безопасней в использовании: grayscaled изображения имеют shape из двух параметров `(h, w)`, а colored изображения имеют shape из трех параметров `(h, w, channels)`, То есть эта запись оставит только `(h, w)` в любом из случаев.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрим официальную [документацию](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be) и видим, что входное изображение должно быть либо 8-битное, либо 32-битное float-point. При этом шаблон должен иметь тот же тип, что и входное изображение. Можете попробовать разбить изображение по каналам и применять шаблон к каждому каналу отдельно